# Should Merged Specs in Dev-Portal also have individual specs for each proxy?

Tags: apigee

In cases where a Product being uploaded to the Dev-Portal has a merged spec for multiple proxies, is it normal to also have an openAPI spec for each proxy contained in the merged Spec?

It's a question of Best-Practices.  Seems to me that each proxy in a spec-first design model would have its individual spec by default.   Then, a second merged spec in the dev-portal.  It would also mean that there are two specs to maintain.

Thanks...

Comment: We do have a similar setup at my organization. We do not maintain multiple API specifications. As far as the consumer is concerned there's an API offering a certain capability. They don't need to know how many proxies the API resolves to. Having to maintain multiple specs does indeed pose unnecessary maintenance problems.